# Media images link to their own image

Tags: 8, theming, media

I have inherited a site which had no image management. Instead each image field required you to upload an image instead of reuse an existing one.
I enabled Media Browser and updated to 8.7.
I am also using the following modules [these are the ones I have installed ontop of existing]:

- embed
- entity_embed
- editor_advanced_link
- inline_entity_form
- entity_browser
- media_entity_browser

The problem is every image, either added via an image filed or in CKEditor wysiwyg is now wrapped in a link to the image file:

```
<a href="/path-to-image/image.ext"><img src="/path-to-image/image.ext"></a>
```

Twig template: \core\modules\image\templates\image-formatter.html.twig

has the following:

```
{% if url %}
  <a href="{{ url }}">{{ image }}</a>
{% else %}
  {{ image }}
{% endif %}
```

But I cannot see where the URL is set in the CMS admin, or how to stop it creating a link to itself. So far I have just copied the template to my theme and removed the url, but I would like to know how to manage this properly.

Answer (score 1):

In: 
structure -> media types -> image -> display

/admin/structure/media/manage/image/display

the image field settings had 'Link image to' -> file

Set this to nothing, removed the theme image-formatter.html.twig template and the file link added to each image was no longer there.